# Rails 4 + Devise + AJAX: Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a subclass of the devise sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    login_process do
      super
    end
  end

  private

    def login_process
      if !anonymous_user?
        old_user = guest_user
      end
      yield
      if user_signed_in?
        current_user.cart.replace_cart_items!(old_user.cart.cart_items) unless old_user.cart.cart_items.empty?
      end
    end

end
```

And the form that I pasted from their site for having customized sign in forms on other pages: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app)

```
    <div class="log_in_div">
        <h3>Log in</h3>
        <%= form_tag session_path(:user), remote: true do %>
            <div>
                <%= label_tag 'user[email]', 'Email' %>
              <%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%= label_tag "user[password]", "Password" %>
              <%= password_field_tag 'user[password]' %>
            </div>

          <%= check_box_tag 'user[remember_me]' %>
          <%= label_tag 'user[remember_me]', 'Remember me' %><br>
          <%= submit_tag "Log in" %>
          <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

However, when I submit the form through the browser, I get this:

```
    Processing by SessionsController#create as JS
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"gfdgdgd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
    Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the ajax call for devise login -

set < config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false > in devise initializer

and set <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in application layout

Answer (score 0):

Add `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!` to SessionsController.